# Drupal 7 Twitter

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, social-network

I have a requirement where I need to tweet through many tweet accounts for which I have username and password.

I have read [many tutorials on `oauth`](http://www.snipe.net/2009/07/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/), but I am still confused about using this for multiple twitter accounts.

Is there any way to achieve the same in Drupal using a module?

Answer (score 3):

The [Twitter module](http://drupal.org/project/twitter) provides a good way to interact with twitter. It allows you to pull/push tweets.
The only problem is that it's not ported yet to Drupal 7, but there is [a long issue on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/780712) already.

Comment: Which has a link to a pretty well working port that is currently hosted on github: https://github.com/GiantRobot/drupal-twitter/tree/7.x-3.x

Comment: where do i get the d7 port of oauth_common module.It is required for Twitter Port module to get enabled.

Comment: ok. i did manage to get the d7 port of oauth_common from https://github.com/GiantRobot/drupal-oauth. But when i enabled all the 5 modules(oauth_common,twitter,twitter-post,twitter-signin,twitter-action) i get this error - `ReflectionException: Function rules_core_action_execute() does not exist in ReflectionFunction->__construct() (line 1382 of \sites\all\modules\rules\includes\rules.core.inc)`

Comment: The D7 version of OAuth 3.x (oauth_common.module) can now be found here: http://drupal.org/project/oauth

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal OAuth module has now been available for some time. It is the best way to use OAuth with Drupal:
https://drupal.org/project/oauth

For those who come here via Google trying to find info about oauth_common after installing or updating twitter_pull (which now requires the twitter module, which leads to an oauth_common dependency.)  You can resolve the oauth_common dependency by installing oauth, which contains oauth_common and oauth_common_providerui modules.

Thanks VoxPelli for pointing the way.